# Solr Suggest AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory

Tags: solr, autosuggest, search-suggestion

I am new for solr and trying to add new suggest feature for my site.
and i already add the suggest feature using AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory to suggest in solrconfig.The suggetion is working fine, but the result in my website is coming like

```
nestle <b>MILO</b> Activ
```

but it should come like

```
"nestle MILO Activ" without the "<b>" "</b>"
```

how can i setup this on solr??

Here is my solrconfig

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggest</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">goodsName</str>
      <str name="weightField">popularity</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_en</str>
      <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>


  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" 
                   >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggest</str>
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [you're using `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/suggester.html#Suggester-AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory), it has a custom configuration parameter that allows you to turn off highlighting:

> **highlight**: Highlight suggest terms. Default is true.

So to avoid highlighting your suggestions, setting `highlight` to false in your configuration should be enough:

```
<str name="highlight">false</str>
```